# how to just receive info from sevlet via jquery without sending request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, servlets

I have a difficulty to deal with the following scenario:

lets say I have 2 jsp pages: page1 and page2

when user click a button in page2 that button sends id to page1 and according to that Id I get some info from database and send the information to java script file related to page 1 now the problem starts:

how can I receive it in javascript file when I did not send a request from that javascript file?

in normal situation it is easy since you send and then you receive the return info in thr point that you sent it but now I am not sending it I want just to receive it and show it in for example div?

Comment: Are both forms on the same page? It would help us if you put your code in your question so we can see.

Comment: Sorry by form I mean two pages I corrceted it

Comment: Are you using php, java, C#, or something else on the backend?

Comment: Actually I have no Idea if it is doable or not that is why I posted here first in order not to go the wrong direction!

Comment: I am using java(jsp-servlet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you insist using javascript read the url at the beginning of second page and manage everything with simple if statement

Answer (score 1):

When form1 button is clicked.Inorder to get data from database..We need to send request to servlet.Its not possible without request.
or you can embed sql queries in jsp itself.

you can have a hidden field in form.when you get response from servlet you change hidden field value.
You can then use document.getelementbyId to get the value in js.
Can you make the question more clearer.

Comment: Yes you are right but we click on page 2 and then we send id to page 1 and then we want to show some info in page 1 not 2

Answer (score 1):

Todo something like this you have to use session data.

[Find a tutorial here on how to do that](http://www.jsptut.com/sessions.jsp)

Hope that helps you.

Comment: thanks it was helpful but still I would rather to use jquery and ajax

Comment: If you need to load a page anyway it will be better to do it server side for several reasons.
1. Reduces the calls to your server.
2. Reduces the load time for your end user.

Answer (score 1):

In order to send id from page2 to page1 .Its better to have a servlet b/w.Its bad idea to redirect from jsp to jsp.
or

You can use sendredirect in jsp page2. send id along with url....After that in page1 you can get data from database using id...
example

```
response.sendRedirect("page1.jsp?name=" + id);
```

Comment: <% 
String display= request.getParameter("id");
%>
You can use this string wherever you wan in jsp

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `jQuery.ajax()` method. You can bind this to a button to send your request to server where it will access the database and then you can get the result in JavaScript file which can be presented as you want with jQuery.

Comment: But I do not click on anything in page 1 I just receive id from page 2 and then after database reteival I want to sent it to a javascript file